# auxiliary do-support: do murder

Tags: legalese, auxiliary-verbs, archaicisms, do-support

The *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, page 98, reads

> Auxiliary *do* was used more widely in earlier stages of the language,
>   and in certain genres one comes across archaic uses that go beyond our
>   *do-support* constructions – e.g. in legal language (*on or about the 14 th day of June, 1997, he **did** murder one James Robinson*)

What type do-support does "*did murder*" represent?

Comment: ***The auxiliaries DO and DOES for emphasis***: https://www.grammaring.com/the-auxiliaries-do-and-does-for-emphasis

Answer (score 3):

This is not [do-support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support) per-se. This sentence is not interrogative or nugatory in nature, and do is coming *after* the subject pronoun he, so there is no [subject/verb inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion). The reason it is coming near the middle of the sentence is because of [fronting](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/fronting), which reorganizes some elements of a sentence to change its focus.

Did is instead being used as a marker of the emphatic mood. According to the Farlex book of Grammar's  [Mood](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Mood.htm) section:

> The “emphatic mood” refers to the use of the auxiliary verb do to add emphasis to a verb that would otherwise not require an auxiliary.
>
> We usually use emphatic do to stress the fact that something is the case.
>   For example:
>   “Yes, I do know that we are meeting your parents tonight.”
>   “Well, she does have a Ph.D., after all.”
>
> We can also use do to add emphasis to demands or requests, as in:
>
> “Do be careful, John.”
>   “Oh, do be quiet!”
>   However, the use of do in such imperative sentences is now rather formal and old fashioned.

In this case it seems to be emphasizing that the fact did happen, [which is common in legal contexts.](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/512593/124936)

Comment: I've also found _I **do** hereby bequeath..._